# How can we use Struts-1 and Spring-Boot together in an application?

Tags: java, spring-boot, struts-1

I'm working in an old web application which is using **Struts-1** with **Hibernate**. There we're using full-fledged functionality of struts1 with *ActionServlet* as the front controller, *struts-config.xml* as configuration file etc. We are using tomcat-9 for deploying and running the war file. Now there's a requirement to use **Rest-API** in the application for which I need to introduce **Spring Boot** in the application for the first time.

I'm little confused, is it really possible to correlate Springboot with Struts1 ??
If yes, then How can I achieve that? Can anyone help me what will be the possible configuration changes, which new files I need create and How they both can work in the application??

Springboot has **embedded tomcat** right? then, how these two different technologies will work together? I need an overall idea for this. Please help.

Comment: I could help you but this is a project and not something that can be answered here

Comment: You don't necessarily **need** spring boot to use rest-api in an application. It certainly makes development easier however for existing projects it might be better to try introducing the spring-web and get dispatcher servlet working first. In fact from past experience for legacy applications with heaps of other dependencies/frameworks I have found migrating to simple spring-webmvc a lot easier than spring-boot. See if you can enable spring context by simply adding relevant dependencies and some minor changes to web.xml

Comment: @Simon Martinelli You can give me the idea of the configuration changes, the files I needed, how I can run the application etc. with your own systematic example. It may be a generic one. But I will understand and change accordingly. 
And if you want know any of my existing configuration, let me know. But it's a huge application, I can not give u all them.

Comment: Maybe this could help https://github.com/lff0305/springboot-lagency-struts-1

Comment: I already saw this link, and this is the only example that I got from internet. But I didn't understand the configuration properly, **web.xml** contains nothing, what is **struts-tiles.xml** for? While you hit the url,, it's directly calling the action class through the url. But how the workflows works, they didn't explain anything.

Comment: @Jerry `struts-tiles` is for... using Tiles with Struts. `web.xml` is empty because its servlets are configured using annotations, see `BootActionServlet`. Why not start looking at it, explore, and experiment a little bit?

Comment: @Dave Newton Okay. My application is already using **struts-1**. It's not using **struts-tiles** now. So, if I want to add **Spring-boot** on top of it, what else changes i require? Should the **web.xml** be empty ??